# Use file.path() in R to paste a vector into a single file path

Tags: r, directory-structure

When I use `file.path()` on a vector of directories, R performs `file.path()` on each element of the vector individually, rather than combining them all into a single folder path.

For example:

```
path <- c('folder1', 'folder2', 'folder3')
file.path(path)
```

does not result in `'folder1/folder2/folder3'`
whereas
`file.path('folder1', 'folder2', 'folder3')` does.

How can I use file.path() with a vector as the input? I call `file.path()` inside a function where the intended path varies, so I can't hardcode the folders in. I know I can use `paste(path, collapse = '/')` but that's slower and the collapse string is platform-dependent.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

We may pass the function in `do.call` with the input converted to a `list` (`as.list`)

```
do.call(file.path, as.list(path))
[1] "folder1/folder2/folder3"
```

Comment: Beat me by 34 secs.